# Dapper ExecuteAsync missing?

Tags: c#, oracle, asynchronous, dapper

I am writing a repo against an Oracle Db using Dapper v 1.50.4 ,Dapper-Async 1.3.0, Oracle.ManagedAccess 12.2.1100, and .Net 4.61 but cannot find the ExecuteAsync method

[image: The SqlMapper class is missing the ExecuteAsync but contains the other async methods]

These are the latest packages from NuGet. Any idea why I am running into this? I just compared this project that implements another prod repo that uses ExecuteAsync and I have no idea what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a mix up with a version of Dapper, or Dapper-Async library.

To verify:

1. I created new console app
2. install-package Dapper

   ```
   class Program
   {
       static async void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var conn = new SqlConnection();
           var x = await conn.ExecuteAsync("select 1");
       }
   }
   ```

Also, I don't think you need "Dapper-Async" library here, Dapper has full support for TLP usage.